# Blend Pixel (Correct way to get a new alpha value for a blended pixel)

Tags: c, graphics, alphablending

I have a function for blending pixels but the alpha value for the new pixel is wrong. Iv tried a few different approaches too fixing this in the past but could never figure out the correct algorithm for generating the correct alpha value.

An example of what I'm attempting to do. Draw testImage2 over testImage1.
The problem may not be obvious when viewing the images on stackoverflow depending on the background color. Try viewing the images with an actual image viewer.

Would prefer to have a solution that doesn't use float or double types. The first parameter is a pointer to the background pixel while the second parameter is the actual pixel value of the front pixel. The 3rd parameter just adjusts the alpha value for the entire pixel.

testImage1:

[image: testImage1]

testImage2:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Actual result:

[image]

The code:

```
struct PIXEL
{
    unsigned char Blue;
    unsigned char Green;
    unsigned char Red;
    unsigned char Alpha;
};

void RenderAlphaPixel(PIXEL* pDestination, U32 Color, unsigned char Alpha)
{
    signed int Alpha2, Remainder, Red, Green, Blue, Alpha3;

    Alpha2 = (Color >> (8 * offsetof(PIXEL, Alpha)));
    Alpha2 -= 255;
    Alpha2 += Alpha;
    if (Alpha2 < 0) Alpha2 = 0;
    Remainder = 255 - Alpha2;

    Red = (unsigned char)(Color >> (8 * offsetof(PIXEL, Red)));
    Green = (unsigned char)(Color >> (8 * offsetof(PIXEL, Green)));
    Blue = (unsigned char)(Color >> (8 * offsetof(PIXEL, Blue)));
    Alpha3 = (unsigned char)(Color >> (8 * offsetof(PIXEL, Alpha)));

    pDestination->Red = (unsigned char)(((pDestination->Red * Remainder) + (Red * Alpha2)) / 255);
    pDestination->Green = (unsigned char)(((pDestination->Green * Remainder) + (Green * Alpha2)) / 255);
    pDestination->Blue = (unsigned char)(((pDestination->Blue * Remainder) + (Blue * Alpha2)) / 255);
    // todo. Fix me!
    pDestination->Alpha = (unsigned char)(((pDestination->Alpha * Remainder) + (Alpha3 * Alpha2)) / 255);
}
```

***EDIT for WENDYN***

When decreasing the alpha of the front image the image becomes very dark. Easy to see the problem when viewing in windows photo viewer.

Expected result:

[image]

Actual result:

[image]

Comment: Aren't the alphas of both images just interpolated with Alpha? I don't think you should add Color's alpha into the calculation there there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try

```
vec4 A, B;
out.rgb = A.rgb * A.a + B.rgb * (1.0 - A.a) * B.a;
out.a = A.a + B.a * (1.0 - A.a)
```

translated to 8 bit channels:

```
U8 aR, aG, aB, aA;
U8 bR, bG, bB, bA;
cR = ((U16)aR * aA + (U16)bR * (255 - aA) / 255 * bA) / 255;
cG = ((U16)aG * aA + (U16)bG * (255 - aA) / 255 * bA) / 255;
cB = ((U16)aB * aA + (U16)bB * (255 - aA) / 255 * bA) / 255;
cA = aA + (U16)bA * (255 - aA) / 255;
```

Comment: Thanks! `cA = min(255, aA + bA)`  appears to have fixed it. To work with my function `bA` had to be replaced with `Remainder`. So it looks like this `pDestination->Alpha = (unsigned char)min(255, Alpha3 + Remainder);`

Comment: I have a question, where did the `pDestination->Alpha` go from the right side? I'm happy it works but I can't see how... Shouldn't it be `pDestination->Alpha = min(255, Alpha3 + pDestination->Alpha)`?

Comment: You are correct, it doesn't work. I have done more testing and find various issues. Using the example you provided has an issue only when i try to decrease the alpha state of the entire front image (calling RenderAlphaPixel with a value of 127 as the 3rd parameter), the front image looks darker than i think it should. I will update the question to show the test results.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Description) wikipedia article it's also `A.a + B.a * (1.0 - A.a)`, I already edited my answer

Comment: I was able to fix the darkening of the image by setting the background color value to white, even though the pixels are transparent it appears to effect the result... The result is still a little different (the shadow of the printer disappears and the edges are rough) even when using `A.a + B.a * (1.0 - A.a)`. I will run some more tests and do some more reading to see if i can find the problem.